# Moving java app from a case insensitive file system to a case sensitive one

Tags: java, windows, linux, case

We have been running our Java code on windows servers for years. We want to run the same code on some FreeBSD boxes but our code has grown up in an environment where file/path name are case insensitive for so long that a lot of the code will break.

What I want to do is some sort of trick where we subclass File or FileSystem or some similar trick and this forces all our file names to lower case (all the time).

It seems pretty possible (i.e. extend File with a new class OurFile that forces everything lower case).  Then we would run a script that turns all files/folders on the OS lower case and bam, bugs squashed.

It seems like some similar hacking with a new FileSystem implementation would also yield a good result.

I then thought -- surely someone before me has faced this issue and licked it good.

So, what is the wisdom out there?  Is there an easy/standard way to fix this sort of case sensitivity problem? (i.e. has someone written LowerCaseFileSystemForPortingWindowsToUnix extends FileSystem, and tested it etc.?)

Comment: The case sensitivity could be solved by having all the data on a case insenstive file system. try http://www.brain-dump.org/projects/ciopfs/

Comment: I looked at ciopfs and determined it's not hardy enough for our purposes.  ZFS has a case insensitive option that we tried ... It worked but some zfs tools had issues/did not properly support this little used option.

Comment: Is it possible to keep the data on windows for a while. in that case mount data from windows with ignore_case and see how much your app can go.  Then fix the code to work with file systm like zfs where other features like journalling, backup-restore etc will be the decision making features.. not case sensitivity

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered fixing your code? From your description, you seem to have a lot of file/resource references which 'case-insensitive' (so, simply speaking, incorrect) names in code... It can be done either by adapting file names to how they are referenced in code (only when there is some consequence in code, f.g. all file names are lower-case) or adapt the constants in code to match file names.

Any wraps to java.io classes would require to list all files/directories anywhere in path and trying to find name that would match the path. However, on U**x system you could have both `resources` and `Resources` directory etc., so which one would you take for path 'RESOURCES/IMAGES/MYIMAGE.PNG'? Additionally, you would suffer from performance issues for I/O operations.

I've once 'fixed' such project, fortunatelly it was quite small, but it was very annoying. For my luck, some operations could be scripted, for example changing all constants in single file to lower-case and lower-casing all image filenames etc.

Comment: The code base is over two million lines.  Plus, all file names are not in code, some are in configuration and data files etc (of which there are 12 tb worth...) so this is not a practical option.

Answer (score -2):

If your file access methods go through a small number of classes (like `new File(String filename)`) then you might be able to use AspectJ to weave in some code which modifies the case of the filename as it is passed through.

Something like:

```
@Around(value = "newFile(context)", argNames = "point")
public Object requiresNew(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {

  String filename = (String) point.getArgs()[0];
  return point.proceed(new String[] { filename.toLowerCase() });
}
```

This would probably be a lot less intrusive on your codebase than extending `File`, plus it would give you an exit strategy:

1. `log.warn()` all filenames passed through which are not entirely lower case
2. Fix the warnings as they arise
3. Remove the aspect once it's bedded in

Comment: If for some reason the file names are generated kept in some registry and then used for comparisons with names obtained fresh from the file system this will fail.

If this is used to point to a file with a name that includes upper case prepackaged with your app installation it will not retrieve the same file. This will only work in cases that involves your writing files that have unique names taking into accounts case sensitivity.

Comment: The question makes no mention of filename registries, besides you could easily aspect those methods to return lowercase entries from the filesystem. I agree that it won't work with mixed case filenames that are packaged, but presumably you could search for those directly and change them. The questions specifically states: "Then we would run a script that turns all files/folders on the OS lower case"

Comment: I don't think there is a single good answer here. There's an information problem: The code doesn't contain the information you need. All solutions will necessarily be incomplete.

Comment: All the information needed is in the code... It's simply that case sensitive file systems add a distinction without a difference.  To us AAA.jpg is the same as aaa.jpg

Comment: As you know a standard unix-style filesystem would disagree: To it AAA.jpg and aaa.jpg are _not_ the same. That's what I mean by incomplete information. I mean information in the "information theory" sense. I'm not trying to criticise your application - I'm just saying that due to this information issue there probably isn't a single nice drop-in solution that will solve every edge case for you.